7-adic cubic root
According to https://oeis.org/A319305:

For $k$ not divisible by 7, $k$ is a cube in the 7-adic field if and only if $k \equiv 1, 6 \pmod{13}$. If $k$ is a cube in the 7-adic field, then $k$ has exactly three cubic roots.

Why is $k \equiv 1, 6 \pmod{13}$ the condition for $k$ to be a cube in the 7-adic field? Is it a typo? I think it should be $k \equiv 1, 6 \pmod{7}$ instead. But I don't know how to prove $k$ has exactly 3 cubic roots. I know it has at most $3$ cubic roots, from Lagrange's theorem. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Related: p-adic cubic root proves the cubic root of $k$ is unique for $p≡2\bmod3$. But  $7≡1\bmod3$.

$\mathbb Z_7$ contains six sixth roots of unity, hence also the third roots of unity. If $a$ is an $n$-th root of $b$, then so is $\zeta a$ for $\zeta$ an $n$-the root of unity.

Start with mod $7$:  $1^3\equiv2^3\equiv4^3\equiv1$ and the opposites cubed are $\equiv-1$. $(\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z)^*\cong\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$

It is a typo (should be $k \equiv 1, 6 \pmod{7}$).  The cubic residues are $1 \ {\rm and} \  -1 \pmod{7}$, and the number of cube roots of unity is 3 (since $3 \mid (7-1)$).  So for each value of $k$, multiply by each cube root of unity to get exactly three cubic roots.

$k$ is a cube mod $13$ and has $3$ cube roots if $k\equiv\pm1,\pm5\bmod13$

It was indeed a typo. Thank you very much for having corrected it! :)

As discussed in comments, the $13$ must be a typo for $7$. The second statement is correct though.
Indeed, if $a \in \mathbb Z_7^\times$ (e.g. $k \in \mathbb Z$ not divisible by $7$), then the polynomial $x^3-a$ has a root modulo $7$ if and only if $a \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{7}$ (direct check in $\mathbb F_7$). Further, Hensel's Lemma guarantees that this is equivalent to it having a root in $\mathbb Z_7$.
Now as also discussed in comments, $\mathbb Z_7$ contains the $6$th roots of unity (for any odd $p$, $\mathbb Z_p$ contains exactly the ($p-1$)-th roots of unity). Since $3$ divides $6$, in particular there are two choices for $\zeta_3 \in \mathbb Z_7$ such that $\zeta_3^3=1\neq \zeta_3$, and by basic algebra, if $x$ is a root of $x^3-a$, then so is $\zeta_3x$, i.e. this polynomial factors completely in $\mathbb Z_7$ if and only if it has a root at all.
